# What is the best way to fetch and store data from ethereum blockchain for migration of contracts?

Tags: ethers.js, migration

So, there is a contract deployed on Ethereum, with a significant amount of storage variables. And I need to migrate them into a new contract. The workflow would be something like this.

1. I will search for a particular event emitted in that contract
2. Based on the data(user address) I get from that event, I will fetch the variables related to that address.
3. I will store all of them in a proper way so that there is no intermingling of data among different user addresses.
4. All of them need to be done programmatically because manually doing so is not feasible.

What is the best way to do it? Although I am aware of the basic ways for this, but need to find more efficient and production-level methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach :

What I did for now is, fetch the desired events using ethers js queryFilter, then store those in the form of an array in a JSON file by converting them into Objects.

Now I can read the JSON file and use the arrays as arguments for the migrate function in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

With [0xweb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/0xweb) tool you could dump the contracts storage first. It collects all the contract state variables from the source, so the contract must be validated on a block explorer, *or if you develop locally with hardhat plugin [0xweb/hardhat](https://github.com/0xweb-org/hardhat) the contract's class with the storage layout is generated automatically*. In the next step, it generates the storage layout slot locations for every variable and reads them from the blockchain with simple `getStorageAt`, so as the result you get the `*.json` file with all the variables and their values, and the `*.csv` with the list of `slot, value`. Later your migration method would accept the array of `slot-value` items and write to its storage with simple assembly `sstore(slot,value)`.

```sh
$ npm i 0xweb -g

# fetches the contract source and generates the contracts client class
$ 0xweb i 0xMY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS --name MyContract --chain eth

# prints the command information
$ 0xweb c ?

# loads the contracts slot values
$ 0xweb c dump MyContract --output ./dumps/my-contract --chain eth
```

`dump/my-contract.json` will be the json file of the contracts storage, `dump/my-contract.csv` will be the `slot-value` list.

> There is an edge-case with the `mapping` type: as it is not possible to iterate over the mapping to get all the keys, the tool will automatically fetch all past logs that lead to `mapping` variable mutation. So the method, that adds new keys to the `mapping` must emit some `event`.

> In case you want to set your RPC nodes, instead of default public, you can do it in configuration:  `$ 0xweb config -e`

Comment: This is interesting, will check it out thanks. Although this is about the storage variables, does this tool have a way to fetch events as well? Coz as I mentioned, the first step is to fetch the events and then storage only related to event data.

Comment: Ah, okay, I thought you needed to migrate just the storage variable values. To fetch and store the events for further processing, for example, the `Transfer` event: `0xweb c logs MyContract Transfer --output trasfers.json` (or to output the csv: `--output transfers.csv`)

Comment: Amazing, will try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. I am very interested to hear experts' answers. However, I have dealt with a similar issue myself and realized there is no low-cost way to do this, unless we had defined the old contract to be upgradeable. Otherwise, you have to re-enter all the data which consumes a lot of gas.

It depends on the contract type - if an admin or a central wallet can do this, it is possible to automatically execute transactions with private keys and back-end code. And if users need to transfer their own data, it has to be done manually by each user approving transactions.

Although you could define functions to handle multiple desired transactions without running into gas limit problems, improving speed and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I am aware of the gas costs in the migration process, and that's fine. The question is more about reading and storing the data from the old contract before migration.

Comment: Try this with web3.js : oldContract.getPastEvents(eventName, {fromBlock, toBlock}, async (error, events) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }
       
      for (let event of events) {
        let userAddress = event.returnValues.user;
        let userData = await oldContract.methods.getUserData(userAddress).call();
      }
    });